# How to transfer apps from a previous iPhone to a new one?

Tags: iphone, applications, icloud

I have recently got a new iPhone. I would like to transfer all my apps that I have previously downloaded (ie: iFruit, BBM, TU Go from O2, etc).

How do I do so without downloading them all again? …and also I need to transfer all my pictures and videos through iCloud but not apps.

Comment: Did you sync your previous iPhone with your computer (via iTunes)?

Answer (score 2):

you can all you need to do is use iTunes and create a backup of your old iphone, after that's dome plug in the new iPhone and choose the previous iPhone backup (old iPhone) and it should work, I have done this since the iPhone 4 so I'm sure it works. The only thing is it takes a while if you have used a lot of your memory.

You can find additional instructions on how to do this on [Apple's support site](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2109).